# Extra file is not uploaded to S3 on sam deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

After I run `sam build` for my application, I add a file (which needs to change on every deployment) to a lambda layer before running `sam deploy`.

I can confirm that the file is created correctly in the right place, but if that's the only change that happened to the layer, when I run `sam deploy` the new file is not detected and the layer is not uploaded at all (because SAM thinks there is no difference).

I don't know how SAM checks for differences, because I would expect a whole new file (or a modified one) in the build folder for a layer to be detected as a change.

I'm aware of the `--force-upload` flag, but I'm under the impression that would force everything to be reuploaded. Given that the application is large, I don't want to do that just to update a single file in a single layer.

Is there a way to force-upload just the layer? Is there something I should be doing when adding arbitrary files to the build so that SAM can detect them?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sam package` to [upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-package.html) the `.zip` to S3.

Comment: According to AWS' own docs, that step is now included in `sam deploy` ("sam deploy now implicitly performs the functionality of sam package. You can use the sam deploy command directly to package and deploy your application"). As stated, the rest of the app is uploaded correctly, only this added file is missing.

Comment: I think it "implicitly" packages the build, but if you do not re-run the `build` after you add the file, then it skips this step and the added file is not reflected in S3 and hence is not deployed.  But I may be wrong.  Just out of interest can you `build` your app, then add the files, then `package` and then `deploy`.  Will it solve the problem?

Comment: I suspect you're right, but I'm on a rather tight schedule so I can't test this (I'm on Windows and need Docker for the build, which makes it rather slow running).

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a workaround than a solution, since this doesn't explain why the problem occurs, but I managed to make it work by adding the file to the layer's code *before* the build process, so that `sam build` then included the file by itself.
This is a bit dirtier because it's a file I don't need to commit to git and that is generated anew on every deployment, so I also needed to add it to .gitignore.

My guess is that the cache is calculated by `sam build` and then trusted by `sam deploy`, so if the build files change in the meantime they are not detected. If that's the case, it's a bit stupid, if you ask me, but it's just a hypothesis.

TL;DR: include any extra files *before* running `sam build`, putting them in the code itself.